# Google Compute Engine with multiple SSH users, Debian

Tags: debian, ssh

I have managed to set up my server with a default user 'admin'. The sshKeys in the metadata is set with the following format, described in the google documentation.

```
 key: sshKeys 
 value: admin:ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXXX
```

However, I am trying to add a new user to the system, hence I updated the metadata to the following

```
 key: sshKeys 
 value: admin:ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXXX newuser:ssh-rsa YYYYYYYYY
```

This has worked perfectly for me on one instance of server that I have set up sometime back. However I was unable to set it up on the new one. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Google Compute Engine developer's console, there is an "SSH Keys" configuration section.  Generating the equivalent REST (JSON in this case) of the metadata, that shows:

> "metadata": { "kind": "compute#metadata", "fingerprint":
>   "some_obfuscated_fingerprint", "items": [{ "key": "sshKeys", "value":
>   "eric:ssh-rsa obfuscated_public_key_here eric@somedomain.com" }]}

So it looks like you have the format for a single key correct (check that you have the username/domain at the end).  But when you have multiple keys, I think you have to add a newline character to separate the list entry for each user:

> "items": [   {
>       "key": "sshKeys",
>       "value": "user1:ssh-rsa AAAA...pIy9 user@host.domain.com\nuser2:ssh-rsa AAAA...ujOz user@host.domain.com" 
>   }  ]

from [the compute engine open source project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/tree/master/google-daemon)